# Fitting bounds with Carto.js?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am new to Carto.js and I don't understand how to work with it SQL.

How do I get bounds for this query?

```
const places = new carto.source.SQL(`SELECT * FROM someTable`);
```

I saw an example with cartoDb

```
sql.getBounds('select * from table').done(function(bounds) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

to get the bounds, but as I understand it is not the same.

Comment: The `bounds` is what you are looking for I think. In what way is it "not the same" same as what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the CARTO SQL API to retrieve that information applying a query with ST_EXTENT and parsing the response.

Here you have an example with simple code that you can use to get it running [Get bounds with SQL API](https://bl.ocks.org/ivanmalagon/4c6607df493cca652624e094568593ec)

Pseudocode for those steps:

```
const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
const username = 'cartojs-test'
const tableName = 'someTable';

const places = new carto.source.SQL(`SELECT * ${tableName}`);

const boundsQuery = `SELECT ST_Extent(the_geom) as extent FROM ${tableName}`;
const boundsUrl = `https://${username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=${query}&api_key=${apiKey}`

fetch(boundsUrl)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(json => {
    const extent = json.rows[0].extent;
    const bounds = parseExtent(extent);
    map.fitBounds(
      [
        [bounds.south, bounds.west],
        [bounds.north, bounds.east]
      ]
    );
  });
```

This code uses ES6 and `fetch` so it'll work on modern browsers. You can use a regular ajax request for that using `axios`, `jquery`or you preferred tool.

The code for the function `parseExtent`is the example [Get bounds with SQL API](https://bl.ocks.org/ivanmalagon/4c6607df493cca652624e094568593ec). It only parses the extent response to a bounds object.

Answer (score 1):

you also need parseExtent:

`function parseExtent (extent) {
const floatRegex = /-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?/g;
 const matches = extent.match(floatRegex);
  return {
   west: Number.parseFloat(matches[0]),
   south: Number.parseFloat(matches[1]),
   east: Number.parseFloat(matches[2]), 
   north: Number.parseFloat(matches[3])
};
}`